# Single Quote and Double Quote Append

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to append a single quote and also add double quote, but it shows an error as follows

> [ts] ':' expected

```
  "id": " + ' + jsonObject["school_id"] + ' + "
```

expected output would be something similar as follows

```
"id" : "'12345'"
```

Comment: why do u want to put it double quotations again.? its string already.!

Comment: It is requirement from service side to handle one composite key. I do not know in depth.

Comment: The word for the character is "quote", not "quota". I had edited, but your later edit replaced mine. You need to match your quotes; Please show the full code, as it is not clear where you are starting from. Also note that `JSON.stringify` might be a better route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just use `'` like that.

If you want to include single quotes in the string, enclose them in a string.

```js
const jsonObject = {"school_id": "12345"}

const obj = {"id": "'" + jsonObject["school_id"] + "'"}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use template strings to easily create it.

```js
let jsonObject = {school_id:"1234"}
let s = `"id" : "'${jsonObject["school_id"]}'"`;
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use Template Strings:

```
const obj = { school_id: "1234" }
const str = `"id" : "'${obj["school_id"]}'"`;
```

I have not worked much with TypeScript, but looks like they are supported:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html

Answer (score 2):

please try this to achieve expected result `"id" : "'12345'"`

```js
var jsonObject = {school_id: 12345}

var a = {"id": '\'' + jsonObject['school_id'] + '\''}

console.log (a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var school_id = '12345';
 school_id = "'"+school_id+"'";
 school_id = '"'+school_id+'"';
 console.log(school_id);
```

You can do like this but make sure you know the use before doing it. don't code blindly.